# A chatbot in Azure's myapps portal for B2B users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

We have rolled out a enterprise wide portal using Azure's myapps where all the enterprise applications are registered. All the B2B users login to this portal and access the application using SSO feature(i.e it uses user's email registered in Azure AD).

i am looking to provide a simple chatbot application in the myapps portal that can resolve any issues related to login to the applications.

Chatbot can be built using powerapps platform.

But how do we integrate or make them available in the myapps portal  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [Documation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-non-gallery-app) on how to add application into Azure AD which would appear automatically in myapps portal.

---

Can try making this setting.
 portal.azure.com -> Enterprise Application -> <<`Your Application`>> -> Self-service

1. Set Yes to "Allow users to request access to this application?"
2. Assign the group "To which group should assigned users be added?"
3. Save the changes and navigate to https://myapplications.microsoft.com/

---

Troubleshooting links:

1. [Access panel troubleshoot application not appearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/access-panel-troubleshoot-application-not-appearing).
2. [Access panel troubleshoot unexpected application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/access-panel-troubleshoot-unexpected-application).

Comment: If I develop a chatbot application it will pop up automatically in myapps portal in my tenant?

Comment: Yes, If your application has the right configuartions as mentioned in the documentations, then it will automatically appear.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify on "right configurations" bit.

Comment: I meant to say, if you follow the documentation step by step, your app will appear in myapps portal.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Hi Divya - I am yet to configure the app. I will let you know once it's done.

Comment: @Prashant Thank you

Comment: Hi Dhivya - I tested this today. I first built a bot using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/python/bot-builder-python-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 and deployed from command line using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/python/bot-builder-python-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 . Still bot app is not visible in myapps portal. App is deployed fine, i verified it using "Test Web Chat" feature.

Comment: @Prashant, I edited the answer with few steps, can you try those and let me know? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Dhivya. It still isn't working. Thanks for your support Dhivya so far

Comment: Is myapplications.microsoft.com different from myapps.microsoft.com ? The former one throws an error but latter one shows my applications except the bot one

Comment: I have added two troubleshoot links in answer for you debug. Are you using Azure AD Application for your bot? Since I don't have access to your application registration, it would be hard for me to find what is missing in the service principal settings.

Comment: Yes. I am using Azure AD application.

Comment: Hi Dhivya. I have not configured SSO for the application. I have configured a group, added a user and mapped it to application by following this procedure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/access-panel-troubleshoot-application-not-appearing#how-to-assign-an-application-to-a-group-directly . Should the bot be configured with SSO? If so why?